# MAMP Pro 6.8.1 SSL with a custom port number

Tags: php, ssl, vuejs3, mamp-pro

I'm running a vue app with a php api. The front end has to run a certain port number. I'm having trouble getting an ssl to run at a url like https://myapp.test:8081. MAMP SSL stuff works like expected in my other hosts, but when I add the port number it says the certificate is invalid or I get some other error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried changing the port numbers in MAMP to match but that gives me errors too. I've tried different port number and forcing the app to run without the port numbers. None of this works.